# Select from two tables statment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Users:

```
id        name       isSpecial
1         Tal        1
2         Jorden     0
3         John       1
4         Paige      0
```

Details:

```
id        userId       Country       zipCode
1         1            Israel        4564
2         3            US            554654
```

I want to get all the data from Users by the name of Jorden OR if isSpecial is 1 to be shown like this

Result:

```
id        name         Country       zipCode
1         Tal          Israel        4564
2         Jorden       
3         John         US            554654
```

I know it's supposed to be a simple query but I can't get the results that I want!

Comment: `... where users.id = details.userId and (users.name='Jorden' OR users.isSpecial = 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.name,
  u.isSpecial,
  d.country,
  d.zipCode
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Detals d
ON u.id = d.userId
WHERE u.name = 'Jorden'
  OR u.isSpecial = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,d.country,d.zipCode FROM
Users u 
LEFT outer JOIN Details d
ON u.id = d.userId
WHERE u.name = 'Jorden' OR u.isSpecial = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Left join would serve your purpose.

SELECT uObj.ID,uObj.Name,DObj.country, DObj.zipcode FROM users uObj LEFT JOIN Details DObj ON uObj.ID=DObj.userID WHERE uObj.name = 'Jorden'
  OR uObj.isSpecial = 1;

Please go through the link below

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Hope this helps you out.